# Raku: How to find all installed modules whose filename matches a pattern?

Tags: module, raku

Is it possible in Raku to find all installed modules whose file-name matches a pattern?

In Perl5 I would write it like this:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );

my %installed;
for my $dir ( @INC ) {
    my $glob_pattern = catfile $dir, 'App', 'DBBrowser', 'DB', '*.pm';
    map { $installed{$_}++ } glob $glob_pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to get the original file name of an installed module. However it is possible to get the module *names*

```
sub list-installed {
    my @curs       = $*REPO.repo-chain.grep(*.?prefix.?e);
    my @repo-dirs  = @curs>>.prefix;
    my @dist-dirs  = |@repo-dirs.map(*.child('dist')).grep(*.e);
    my @dist-files = |@dist-dirs.map(*.IO.dir.grep(*.IO.f).Slip);

    my $dists := gather for @dist-files -> $file {
        if try { Distribution.new( |%(from-json($file.IO.slurp)) ) } -> $dist {
            my $cur = @curs.first: {.prefix eq $file.parent.parent}
            take $_ for $dist.hash<provides>.keys;
        }
    }
}

.say for list-installed();
```

see: [Zef::Client.list-installed()](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/blob/710034fe3537826548d7f5c8983b3fb2db1e17de/lib/Zef/Client.rakumod#L998-L1011)

Comment: Note there is a PR that allows the original file names to be retained, so maybe in the future [rakudo PR#729](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/729/files#diff-9d9f3b6271234e410619d222c23d08f7R198)